# Nested observables to handle errors

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs

What I want to do is to capture success/failure HTTP requests and send them down the same stream to let subscribers be in charge of handling everything.

What I have done thus far is to handle a HTTP error case by using a nested observable. The successful login is forwarded on the stream so that `success` can handle it. But when an error occurs, the `Object.create` is never handled by `fails`

Is there a way to get both the success and failure HTTP request to all be handled within the same stream and let downstream subscribers deal with the failure cases?

```
private actions$ = new BehaviorSubject<Action>({type: actions.INIT, payload: null})

let logins = this.actions$
  .filter(action => return action.type === actions.LOGIN_USER )
  .do(() => this.store.dispatch({ type: actions.LOGIN_REQUEST }) )
  .mergeMap(action => {
    const query = Observable.defer(() => this.http.post('/auth/login', JSON.stringify(action.payload)) );
    return query.catch(err => {
      return Observable.create(err.json());
    })
  })
  .share();

// Works
var success = logins.filter(res => res.success).map(res => store.dispatch({...});
// Failure cases are never dispatched
var fails = logins.filter(res => !res.success).map(res => store.dispatch({...}));
```

When I implement the above, I end up getting `EXCEPTION: TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function`

Comment: Switch out Observable.[create](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md). Observable.[of](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md) is what you want when simply creating an observable emitting the passed in value(s) :)

Comment: Sweet, if you create an answer instead of a comment, I'll mark this as answered!